# Add a class in a table of webmail body?

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
WebMail.Send(to: companyEmail,    
subject: "Message From - " + firstName +" "+ lastName,
                body: "<table>"+
                "<tr>"+
                "<td>Email"+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+email+"</td>"+
                "</tr>"+
                "<tr>"+
                "<td>Phone"+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+phone+"</td>"+
                "</tr>"+
                "<tr>"+
                "<td>Message"+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+message+"</td>"+
                "</tr>"+
                "</table>" // This works just fine
```

But I want to add a class to that table. Say a bootstrap class "table table-striped". The following doesn't run. Any help? How to properly add that class? Thank you

```
WebMail.Send(to: companyEmail,
subject: "Message From - " + firstName +" "+ lastName,
            body: "<table class="table table-striped">"+
            "<tr>"+
            "<td>Email"+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+email+"</td>"+
            "</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+
            "<td>Phone"+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+phone+"</td>"+
            "</tr>"+
            "<tr>"+
            "<td>Message"+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+message+"</td>"+
            "</tr>"+
            "</table>"
);
```

Comment: you need to escape the quote `"` characters with `\"`

Comment: You can't reference the bootstrap library from an email. You need to add the 'table' and 'table-striped' classes manually to your email body as inline css. This is the same for any css classes in emails. The bootstrap css probably won't render correctly in all email clients as it's designed for the browser, so you'll need to test your email styles in something like http://litmus.com

Comment: So I used \" and then also added custom css for my table instead of using bootstrap class. I still have same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quote `"` characters with `\"`

```
body: "<table class=\"table table-striped\">"+
```